# Update styles automatically

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When you open a document that is based on the template that has been changed since the last time you edited the document, there will be a warning message:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this window and update the styles in the document automatically when you open it?

(I know there is such an option to avoid the warning dialog when you try to insert a linked image. You need to proceed to Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced > Open Expert Configuration, and then change the value of `ShowLinkWarningDialog` under `org.openoffice.Office.Common` to `False`. I need the same option for the window shown above.)

Comment: I think automatically changing style content on opening a document would defeat the concept of a style. I keep documents clear of most styles and add styles as I need.

Comment: I don't see why you think this would defeat something. I have 100 documents that are based on the template Foo. Then I need to adjust the Foo template in some way. And then each of these 100 documents will prompt me to update its styles. And I will need to press the "Update Styles" button each time. This warning dialog is just a safety belt; sometimes it is useful, but sometimes is not.